# How would you implement function rich forms to your module

Tags: 7, forms, webforms

I'm having a hard time deciding on how to develop the following functionality in my upcoming module:

I'm developing a module which should eventually be able to create "event" type nodes. Which extend the nodes functionality to have:

1. One or multiple **plannings** which consist out of...
2. ... **timespaces**, which has the following properties, per timespace:

   - **from** (datetime)
   - **to** (datetime)
   - **limit of subscribers** (int)
   - And other stuff (not related to the question)
3. The website visitors should be able to subscribe to each timespace with a form, filling out their information. But if, and only if the **limit of subscribers** has not been reached yet for this timespace.
4. After subscription, the visitor should get an automatic mail with a PDF (ticket) attached to it.
5. Our customer should be able to **export all the data**, at any time to an Excel sheet...
6. ... and (preferably) quick-review all the subscriptions at all time.

Well, the **plannings** and the **timespaces** won't be a problem, I'll manage that. But I would absolutely LOVE to incorporate [Webforms](http://drupal.org/project/webform/) into this. Since, point 3 through 6 all address functionality that already exists in Webforms... It'll save my butt a lot of time developing this thing.

**My question is**... Does anyone have any experience developing a module, incorporating Webforms? If so, how did you combine the two? I was thinking about something in the lines of:

- Developing a new Field widget which would make it possible for the moderators to create the event's plannings and timespaces.
- Somehow, (and this is the part where I'm not sure how to do this) creating a field for "webform" that would fetch the possibilities from the field.

I'm not sure.. I don't think this is the right way to go... I wonder what you guys think about this and if I simply should develop my own form + all the functionalities with it. Or maybe know a contrib module that does all of this...

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution today myself. I've been developing Webform components. I've found this way to be the best solution without altering any database structures and still getting the full functionality I wanted to get.

## Instantiating - The base of your webform component

[hook_webform_component_info](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_webform_component_info/7) - will be your friend in defining your components base structure. Since I needed the **planning** which would consist out of more **timespaces** (could've done better here on the termonology ;) ), I added a component named "*planning*" and gave it a "feature": group. This way I can extend the component "*planning*" with the "*timespace*" component.

## Values - Add a limit of subscriptions and other parameters for your timespace

[_webform_edit_component](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/_webform_edit_component/7) - Makes it possible to alter the edit form of your component. Make sure you at least add an "limit_subscription" (adjust naming to your liking) field so we can check against it.

[_webform_defaults_component](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/_webform_defaults_component/7) - Will be needed to inject the defaults to your edit form, which you have created with the function here above.

## Cosmetics and security - Make sure you get the checkbox and disable it when full

[_webform_render_component](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/_webform_render_component/7) - Arranges all the cosmetics on your webform component. So make sure you edit your **timespace** component to get the checkbox you want so people can check a timespace. Also, you can (ofcourse) add some additional markup to your liking.

**Security, checking the limit**

This is also the right place to check for your limits and disabling the checkbox when full. (see the function `webform_events_check_timespace_limit($component)`, use that to set `#disabled` on your element. Also make sure you give your element the right validation, something like this, so they can't screw around by simply enabling the checkbox:

```
'#element_validate' => array('_webform_validate_timespace'),
```

Then check against the database in your validation function for the limits, this is how I got it done:

```
/**
 * Validation for timespace elements
 */
function _webform_validate_timespace ($element, &$form_state) {
    // If checked, make sure this timespace has some space left.
    if ($element['#value'] === 1) {
        $remaining_subscriptions = webform_events_check_timespace_limit($element['#webform_component']);
        if ($remaining_subscriptions === -1) form_error($element, t('The timespace that you\'ve chosen is already full!'));
    }
}

/** 
 * Check if the limit has been reached, returns remaining count to the limit, or -1 when full, or FALSE when no limit is set
 */
function webform_events_check_timespace_limit ($component) {
    $limit_subscriptions = $component['extra']['timespace_properties']['limit_subscriptions'];
    if (!empty($limit_subscriptions)) {
        $count_subscriptions = webform_events_get_timespace_count($component['nid'], $component['cid']);
        if ($count_subscriptions >= $limit_subscriptions) return -1;
        else return $limit_subscriptions - $count_subscriptions;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

/**
 * Get the count of the current timespace subscriptions
 */
function webform_events_get_timespace_count ($nid, $cid) {
    $select = db_query('SELECT count(*) FROM {webform_submitted_data} WHERE nid = :nid AND cid = :cid AND data = 1', array(':cid' => $cid, ':nid' => $nid));
    return $select->fetchColumn();
}
```

## Backoffice - Exporting, table views, analysis..

For this you need the following functions, I'm not writing out these, I could go publish a book if I would:

**Exporting (CSV, Excel):**

- [_webform_csv_data_component](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/_webform_csv_data_component/7) - The actual data per row.
- [_webform_csv_headers_component](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/_webform_csv_headers_component/7) - The headers in the top of the sheet.

**Submission view** (The page you get at individual submissions)

- [_webform_display_component](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/_webform_display_component/7)

**Table view**

- [_webform_table_component](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/_webform_table_component/7)

**Analysis view**

- [_webform_analysis_component](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/_webform_analysis_component/7)

## More help

Since I've just outlined the basics of this thing, I'd recommend you check out [some good examples](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/sites%21all%21modules%21webform%21webform.api.php/7).

I've managed to figure this all out and fix get somewhat of the following (of course; early beta screenshots)

**Submission view**
[image: Submission view]

**Analysis view**
[image: Analysis view]

**A simple export**
[image: Export]

**Front-end example**
[image: Front end]

**Table view**
[image: Table]

**Setting up a event**
[image: Setup]